# Boto3 and Sagemaker Access Issues whehn creating Training job

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

```
 botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: User: arn:aws .... is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:... because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob action
```

I have a message as above.
Is there anyway to specify my

```
sm_boto3 = boto3.client("sagemaker")
```

so that this sm_boto3 instance will allow me to create a training job ?

Answer (score 0):

The role or the user that you intend to use should have permissions to create the training job.

Then you need to configure the credentials as given in this link:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html